# Error while building Hadoop src using maven

Tags: java, apache, maven, hadoop, msbuild

I want to install hadoop single node setup on windows7 64 bit.  I have installed cygwin, windows SDK 7.1, maven 3.1.1 and jdk 1.6.33.

Running Hadoop single node setup on windows 7 is very trooublesome.

While buiding the  "mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar" i am getting below error.

Can someone help how to fix this error or any other way to build hadoop on windows 7 64 bit?

portion of the Error log is as follows:

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.461s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 11 19:42:25 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/339M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
5.1:compile (default-compile) on project hadoop-common: Compilation failure: Com
pilation failure:
[ERROR] D:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\java\org\apache\had
oop\ipc\protocolPB\RefreshCallQueueProtocolPB.java:[26,65] package org.apache.ha
doop.ipc.proto.RefreshCallQueueProtocolProtos does not exist
[ERROR] D:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\java\org\apache\had
oop\ipc\protocolPB\RefreshCallQueueProtocolPB.java:[36,33] package RefreshCallQu
eueProtocolService does not exist
[ERROR] D:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\java\org\apache\had
oop\ipc\protocolPB\RefreshCallQueueProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:[24,65] p
ackage org.apache.hadoop.ipc.proto.RefreshCallQueueProtocolProtos does not exist
```

Comment: can you please post your pom.xml

Comment: why do you want to compile from scratch? You can get the compiled sources from hadoop website.

Comment: @Vinay hadoop-common POM.xml file is as follows

Comment: @jithinjustin i am compiling from scratch beacause from Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 release officially supports for running Hadoop on Microsoft Windows as well. But the bin distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 release does not contain some windows native components (like winutils.exe, hadoop.dll etc). As a result, if we try to run Hadoop in windows, we'll encounter ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest hadoop release from this url:

```
http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hadoop/common/stable/hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: I wwas referring to below link for hadoop setup on windows...  http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os#comment-1356133184

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating yourself for no reason: you only need to build hadoop in windows if your system is 32 bits (and good luck on that: I've been trying it for 3 weeks!). Since your system is 64 all you need to do is download a precompiled package

Comment: This might be better as a comment rather than an answer.